# run command if validation fail rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, callback

I want run these commands:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmp/*")
```

**if validation fail in my model with a callback:**

I have seen callback `after_validation`.

How can I check if validation is OK or if the validation is incorrect (KO) with `after_validation` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is:

```
after_validation :empty_tmp

  protected
  def empty_tmp
   if self.errors.any?
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmp/*")
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check with

```
if your_model.errors.empty?
   # run commands
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_validation :do_something_if_validation_fails, :unless => lambda { errors.empty? }

  protected
  def do_something_if_validation_fails
    logger.info "Validation failed lets do something"
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a shame because it looks nice.

Comment: You don't see the gotcha, right? By specifying `:unless => :valid?` you'll trigger validation callbacks from the validation callback.